# Automatic database manipulations using Symfony every month

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I have a use case  where i need to do certain database manipulations automatically   every month on a specific date.Currently using Symfony 2.7 framework is it possible to call a controller every month on a specific date??.Any feedback's/ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling a controller, you could probably create a Symfony Console Command. Have a look here at how to do it: https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/console.html

With this option, the only way to execute it would be via the cli.

Then you can call the command from a cron job that runs at the time you want. Some examples of how to schedule jobs using crontab: https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/

Answer (score 3):

You can make a Console Command in Symfony and call this command every month with a cron task.

[Console command](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/console.html)